# ClickableSpan - Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new at Android development. I've been getting this error, since I tried to add in the option for opening a pop up window (the `onClick()`).

Looks like the error is at line 29->36, as I don't get this error once I comment out that section.

Anyone got an idea what's going on?

My code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.PrivacyPolicyConfirmation);

        String text = "I hereby confirm to have read and understood the Privacy Policy";

        SpannableString checkBoxSS = new SpannableString(text);

        ClickableSpan clickableSpanPrivacyPolicy = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                ds.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                ds.setUnderlineText(true);
            }
        };

        checkBoxSS.setSpan(clickableSpanPrivacyPolicy, 49, 63, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        textView.setText(checkBoxSS);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, PopUpPrivacy.class));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Line 29 being the `ClickableSpan` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ClickableSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) class is an abstract class, which means that some methods have been defined but not implemented. In your case you've not implemented the abstract [`onClick()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html#onClick(android.view.View)) method, which is why you're getting the error. So you'll need to declare the `onClick()` method like so:

```
ClickableSpan clickableSpanPrivacyPolicy = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        ds.setUnderlineText(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        // Do something
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your anonymous `ClickableSpan` class must implement `onClick(View view)` or be declared abstract:

```
ClickableSpan clickableSpanPrivacyPolicy = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        ds.setUnderlineText(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){ }
};
```